# loading native libraries in hadoop reducer?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, native

I have a native library I need to load for my reduce method and I added it to the distributed cache but when I call System.loadLibrary(mylib.so) in my map method I get an error  and failed map task:

```
Error: no mylib.so in java.library.path
```

Even though I added it to the distributed cache.  Am I missing a step?  In my job configuration I call:

```
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(uri, job.getConfiguration());
```

Where the uri is the path to mylib.so on the hadoop file system.

This native library depends on many others, all existing on my /hadoop/fs/mystuff/libs on the hadoop fs.  I add them all to the distributed cache and I even tried loading all of them in my reduce task using the System.loadLibrary() call.  But I keep getting that same java.library.path error.  I also tried adding the libraries as command line arguments to the -files flag but I still get the error above.

Answer (score 0):

Though exactly not sure why this is happening, check the [How to Include Third-Party Libraries in Your Map-Reduce Job](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/) blog entry from Cloudera.

Comment: The above links seems broken. New link : http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/

Answer (score 0):

Do you try our code standalone, not in map-reduce? What I know, System.loadLibrary expect library name without ".so" or ".dll" suffix...