# Load Native Shared Libraries in a HBase MapReduce task

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, java-native-interface

Recently I'm trying to implementing my algorithm in JNI codes(using C++).I did that and generate a shared library. 
Here is my JNI class.

```
    public class VideoFeature{
        // JNI Code Begin
        public native static  float Match(byte[] testFileBytes, byte[] tempFileBytes);
        static {
            System.loadLibrary("JVideoFeatureMatch");
        }
        // JNI Code End
    }
```

In the main function, I write

```
    //  MapReduce
        Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();

    //  DistributedCache shared library
        DistributedCache.createSymlink(conf);
    //  Both following ways seem work.
    //  DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI("/home/danayan/Desktop/libJVideoFeatureMatch.so#JVideoFeatureMatch"), conf);
        DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI("hdfs://danayan-pc:9000/lib/libJVideoFeatureMatch.so#libJVideoFeatureMatch.so"), conf);
```

In map method, codes following work.

```
 public  static class MatchMapper extends TableMapper<Text, IntWritable> {

        @Override
        public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable key, Result values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        // Other codes
        Path[] localFiles = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(context.getConfiguration());
        for(Path temp:localFiles) {
            String path = temp.toString();
            if(path.contains("JVideoFeatureMatch")) {
                 System.out.println("JVideoFeatureMatch  found !");
            }
        }
}
```

In other words, it seems that I 'DistributedCache' my shared library successfully.But I can't load it in the Map function.

```
 public  static class MatchMapper extends TableMapper<Text, IntWritable> {

    @Override
    public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable key, Result values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // Other codes
    int score = (int)VideoFeature.Match(testBytes, tempBytes);
}
```

When I try to call the static function in the JNI class, a 'java.lang.Exception' is thrown :

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libJVideoFeatureMatch in java.library.path.
```

I have also tried 'System.load()'. And I have considered the use of prefix 'lib' and suffix '.so' in Linux system.

What's more, I set a jvm argument (Removing it makes no difference):

```
  -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64
```

And I have loaded the shared library in local machine successfully by moving the shared library to the 'Java.library.path'(set above).

I have browsed some web site below:

[Issue loading a native library through the DistributedCache](http://hadoop.6.n7.nabble.com/Issue-loading-a-native-library-through-the-DistributedCache-td3856.html)

[Native Libraries Guide](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/NativeLibraries.html#Native_Shared_Libraries)
[loading native libraries in hadoop reducer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962508/loading-native-libraries-in-hadoop-reducer)

I don't know if that I said clearly.If not, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

1. First copy the library to HDFS:

   ```
   bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal mylib.so.1 /libraries/mylib.so.1
   ```
2. The job launching program should contain the following:

   ```
   DistributedCache.createSymlink(conf);   
   DistributedCache.addCacheFile("hdfs://host:port/libraries/mylib.so.1#mylib.so", conf);
   ```
3. The MapReduce task can contain:

   ```
   System.load((new File("mylib.so")).getAbsolutePath());
   ```

**The third point is different from the official documentation**

Official documentation : [Native Shared Libraries](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/native_libraries.html#Native+Shared+Libraries)