# Use native shared library in Hadoop Mapreduce: no XXX in java.library.path

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Recently I'm trying to use a native shared library in hadoop Map task, but the hadoop was always unable to load it.
I run my hadoop jar like this:

```
hadoop jar my.jar -files libMylib.so
```

And in the Map task, I try to do this:

```
System.loadLibrary("Mylib"); // have tried to ues "libMylib.so" too
```

I always get the error below:

```
no Mylib in java.library.path
```

I print the java.library.path in the application(main function):

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
```

And get this:

```
/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/native/Linux-amd64-64
```

But in the official documentation, I read this

> The child-jvm always has its current working directory added to the
>   java.library.path and LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Why the java.library.path just only includes one path ?
I copy my lib 'libMylib.so' to every node, and hadoop is able to load it.But it seems not a good idea to copy every native shared library to every node.

I just want to distribute my lib to every node by using  argument '-files libMylib.so', and load it in the Map task.How can I do that ?

[A related question I asked 7 days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845955/load-native-shared-libraries-in-a-hbase-mapreduce-task)

Related website:

[MapReduce Tutorial](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/mapred_tutorial.html#Distributing+Libraries)

[Native Shared Libraries](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/native_libraries.html#Native+Hadoop+Library)

Answer (score 0):

1. First copy the library to the HDFS:
   bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal mylib.so.1 /libraries/mylib.so.1
2. The job launching program should contain the following:
   DistributedCache.createSymlink(conf);
   DistributedCache.addCacheFile("hdfs://host:port/libraries/mylib.so.1#mylib.so", conf);
3. The MapReduce task can contain:
   System.load((new File("mylib.so")).getAbsolutePath());

**The third point is different from the official documentation**

Official documentation : [Native Shared Libraries](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/native_libraries.html#Native+Shared+Libraries)